# How do I sort a dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary

The problem is a list of room numbers and guest details I ripped straight from a txt file that needs to be put into a dictionary with the room number as the keys and the details as the values.

The guest list is literally a list, each item represents room number, guest name, arrival, departure dates. Rooms without anything next to them are empty.

```
nlist = [['101'], ['102'], ['103'], 
['201', ' John Cleese', ' 5/5/12', ' 5/7/12'], ['202'], 
['203', ' Eric Idle', ' 7/5/12', ' 8/7/12'], ['301'], ['302'], ['303']]
```

Basically, got to get that into a dictionary.  Here's what I tried:

```
guests = {}
for i in nlist:
        if len(i) == 1:
            key = i[0]
            guests[key] = None
        else:
            key = i[0]
            val = i[1],i[2],i[3]
            guests[key] = val
```

which gives me:

```
guests = {'201': (' John Cleese', ' 5/5/12', ' 5/7/12'), 
'203': (' Eric Idle', ' 7/5/12', ' 8/7/12'), '202': None, '301': None, 
'302': None, '303': None, '102': None, '103': None, '101': None}
```

As you can see the dictionary is put together in no particular order.  However for this particular exercise, the dictionary needs to be in order from lowest to highest room number.  I guess I thought that it would just iterate through each internal list from beginning to end, test it, and just build the dictionary in that order.

Does anyone know how to write the code correctly so that the dictionary comes out as {'101': None, '102', None, '103': None... etc.)? And hopefully someone could explain why my code didn't work as I intended too.

Comment: Dictionary entries are stored as hashes and are, by nature, unordered. Does your homework require you to use a dictionary? Why do you need them ordered?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Items ordering in Python dictionary](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127945/items-ordering-in-python-dictionary)

Comment: Sorry guys, my title is a bit misleading, isn't it? I was more so interested in why the dict gets jumbled in that particular way. What I've gathered from all your answers is that 'it just is' lol yes, it does require a dictionary but I might be able to get away with an unordered one if i use aix's code below

Comment: @bang: Dictionaries achieve fast lookup times by mapping each key to a location in memory via a _hash function_. This means that the hash function determines the order of the keys. Depending on the specific hash function, this order may be different. This article might be informative: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table .

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Standard Python dictionaries are inherently unordered.

One possibility is to use [`OrderedDict`](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict). It will preserve the *insertion order*, meaning that you have to insert entries in the order in which you then wish to retrieve them.

Another possibility is to keep the `dict` as is, but iterate in the desired order:

```
for k, v in sorted(guests.items()):
  print k, v
```

Finally, it should be noted that your example stores room numbers as strings rather than integers. This means that the ordering is lexicographic (`'90' > '100'`). Since this is homework, I leave it as an exercise for the reading to figure out how to fix this.

Comment: Good edit. It's possible (as this is homework) that OP can only use certain data types.

Comment: It's important to point out that OrderedDict's ordering is based on insertion order, rather than the key (room number), so depending on the input text file, it may not be suitable.

Comment: Beware that the room numbers are actually strings and the sort is lexicographical.  If the smaller numbers are written as `'5'` and not `'005'`, it will not work. If this can be the case, one option is to convert them to integers.

Comment: `for k, v in sorted(guests.items())` also works and avoids having to redo the dictionary lookup.

Comment: Thanks for your responses guys.  The questions states the keys must be stored as strings and all the rooms are 3 digits long, so I probably won't encounter that problem.  I understand what you're saying though.  I think I should be able to use the unordered dict and iterate in the right order like you said.