# sorting python dictionary list

Tags: python

I have this code:

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

TABLE_CONTENT = [['958','<a id="958F" href="javascript:c_row(\'958\')" title="go to map"><img src="/images/c_map.png" border="0"></a>','USA','Atmospheric','<a href="javascript:c_ol(\'958\')" title="click date time to show origin_list (evid=958)">1945/07/16 11:29:45</a>','33.6753','-106.4747','','-.03','21','','','TRINITY','&nbsp;','&nbsp;','<a href="javascript:c_md(\'958\')" title="click here to show source data">SourceData</a>','&nbsp;'],['959','<a id="959F" href="javascript:c_row(\'959\')" title="go to map"><img src="/images/c_map.png" border="0"></a>','USA','Atmospheric','<a href="javascript:c_ol(\'959\')" title="click date time to show origin_list (evid=959)">1945/08/05 23:16:02</a>','34.395','132.4538','','-.58','15','','','LITTLEBOY','&nbsp;','&nbsp;','<a href="javascript:c_md(\'959\')" title="click here to show source data">SourceData</a>','&nbsp;']]

EVENT_LIST = []
for EVENT in TABLE_CONTENT:
    events = {}
    for index, item in enumerate(EVENT):
        if index == 0:
            events['id'] = item
        if index == 4:
            soup = BeautifulSoup(item)
            for a in soup.findAll('a'):
                events['date'] = ''.join(a.findAll(text=True))
        if index == 2:
            events['country'] = item
        if index == 3:
            events['type'] = item
        if index == 5:
            events['lat'] = item
        if index == 6:
            events['lon'] = item
        if index == 8:
            events['depth'] = item
        if index == 9:
            events['yield'] = item
        if index == 12:
            events['name'] = item
    sorted(events, key=lambda key: events['id'])
    EVENT_LIST.append(events)
    print '=== new record ==='
EVENT_LIST.sort(key=lambda x: x['id'])
print EVENT_LIST
```

the first issue, i have is that within the EVENT_LIST the dictionary objects are not in the same order as they have been added to the list, for example, the 'lat' and 'lon' when i print the results are not in order:

```
[{'name': 'TRINITY', 'country': 'USA', 'lon': '-106.4747', 'yield': '21', 'lat': '33.6753', 'depth': '-.03', 'date': u'1945/07/16 11:29:45', 'type': 'Atmospheric', 'id': '958'}, {'name': 'LITTLEBOY', 'country': 'USA', 'lon': '132.4538', 'yield': '15', 'lat': '34.395', 'depth': '-.58', 'date': u'1945/08/05 23:16:02', 'type': 'Atmospheric', 'id': '959'}]
```

also is there a better way to write this code?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Items ordering in Python dictionary](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127945/items-ordering-in-python-dictionary)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can preserve the order of insertions into a dictionary by using an [OrderedDict](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) container. From the manual:

> Return an instance of a dict subclass, supporting the usual dict
>   methods. An OrderedDict is a dict that remembers the order that keys
>   were first inserted. If a new entry overwrites an existing entry, the
>   original insertion position is left unchanged. Deleting an entry and
>   reinserting it will move it to the end.

This feature has only been around since version 2.7.

@Better way: You might change subsequent `if index == ...` to `elif index == ...` since, if the index is 2, it never can be 5. Or you could store index/key combinations and use those to store your items. Example (not tried):

```
combos={
        0: 'id',
        2: 'country',
        3: 'type',
        5: 'lat',
        6: 'lon',
        8: 'depth',
        9: 'yield',
        12: 'name' }

...

for index, item ...:
    if index == 4:
        soup = BeautifulSoup(item)
        for a in soup.findAll('a'):
        events['date'] = ''.join(a.findAll(text=True))
    elif index in combos:
        events[combox[index]]=item
```

I think you get the idea.

Answer (score 1):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/526131/735204

Dictionaries are unordered by definition, as they're stored internally as hash tables. The lack of ordering is a consequence of the algorithm by which keys are inserted and removed from the hash table. Thus, you should never depend on a dictionary's keys being in any particular order. Maybe consider using a tuple instead, or a list of dictionaries - the latter will allow you to maintain a key:value format while also guaranteeing a reliable ordering.

If you're really set on using a dictionary, you might also want to look at OrderedDict, although IMHO if you're using a dict and requiring it to be ordered, you're thinking about the data the wrong way and there's probably a simpler way to do it. http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict

For the curious, this is a great presentation explaining exactly why it is that Python dictionaries have undefined orderings http://blip.tv/pycon-us-videos-2009-2010-2011/pycon-2010-the-mighty-dictionary-55-3352147

Comment: I'm actually favoriting this question because of that fantastic link you posted about how dicts actually work.  (+1).  *sigh*.  I wish I could just favorite an answer ...

Comment: "Thus, you should never depend on a dictionary's keys being in any particular order."  Well, unless you need to: http://stromberg.dnsalias.org/~strombrg/python-tree-and-heap-comparison/

Answer (score 0):

Dictionaries in Python are unordered by default.

You can use [OrderedDict](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) instead. Note that this is only available in Python 2.7+

Answer (score 0):

Better code for your conversion:

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

HEADERS = ['id', None, 'country', 'type', 'date', 'lat', 'lon', None, 'depth', 'yield', None, None, 'name']
TABLE_CONTENT = [['958','<a id="958F" href="javascript:c_row(\'958\')" title="go to map"><img src="/images/c_map.png" border="0"></a>','USA','Atmospheric','<a href="javascript:c_ol(\'958\')" title="click date time to show origin_list (evid=958)">1945/07/16 11:29:45</a>','33.6753','-106.4747','','-.03','21','','','TRINITY','&nbsp;','&nbsp;','<a href="javascript:c_md(\'958\')" title="click here to show source data">SourceData</a>','&nbsp;'],['959','<a id="959F" href="javascript:c_row(\'959\')" title="go to map"><img src="/images/c_map.png" border="0"></a>','USA','Atmospheric','<a href="javascript:c_ol(\'959\')" title="click date time to show origin_list (evid=959)">1945/08/05 23:16:02</a>','34.395','132.4538','','-.58','15','','','LITTLEBOY','&nbsp;','&nbsp;','<a href="javascript:c_md(\'959\')" title="click here to show source data">SourceData</a>','&nbsp;']]

EVENT_LIST = []
for EVENT in TABLE_CONTENT:
    events = {}
    for index, item in enumerate(EVENT):
        if index != 4:
            events[HEADERS[index]] = item
        if index == 4:
            soup = BeautifulSoup(item)
            for a in soup.findAll('a'):
                events[HEADERS[index]] = ''.join(a.findAll(text=True))
    sorted(events, key=lambda key: events['id'])
    EVENT_LIST.append(events)
    print '=== new record ==='
EVENT_LIST.sort(key=lambda x: x['id'])
print EVENT_LIST
```

Answer (score 0):

First some comments about your code:

1. why do you call it `events` if it is inside a loop? It is only one `event`
2. why do you reuse the `events` variable for different event? It can be dangerous for example if an event is bad formatted, for example without an item
3. `sorted` is a no-op in your code, it has no side effect
4. why do you use CAPITAL for non-constant variable?

The issue on the dictionay is not a real issue, it is a feature: the keys are ordered by their hash because `dict` is hash-based. If you really need to conserve the order you can use `collections.OrderedDict`

By the way, here an example:

```
import operator

event_list = []
for event in TABLE_CONTENT:
    event_dict = {}
    event_dict['id'] = event[0]
    event_dict['country'] = event[2]
    # ...
    event_dict['name'] = event[12]
    event_list.append(event_dict)
event_list = sorted(event_list, key = operator.itemgetter('id'))
print event_list
```